# Replace Alt+Click Binding Of Mylyn

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn

Is there anyway that I could replace the Alt+Click Binding of mylyn in eclipse.
I use alt+click to show or hide files of active task

It really is in conflict with my operating system's alt+click function.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the most annoying issues with Mylyn. And actually the reason is the Eclipse SWT which
does not support to bind the META or WIN key instead of Alt-Click.

So for the moment the only option is to reconfigure the window manager.

Comment: see its a resolved bug of eclipse.. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=55236

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> instead.